# Load balancer to distribute READ and WRITE queries to SLAVE or MASTER instance respectively

Tags: postgresql

Currently we keep two different connections to master and slave in our project code and send queries to specific one depending on whether it is a read-only or a data modification query.

Is there a load balancer which distributes queries based on R/W criterion automatically between PostgreSQL cluster nodes (including functions)?

Comment: pgPool and pgBouncer can both do that if I'm not mistaken

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name hello, what about functions, are both aware whether a function performs data mutation or not?

Comment: @gumkins no.  From what I understand, you handle this yourself in application code.

Comment: You can whitelist and blacklist functions in pgPool: http://www.pgpool.net/docs/latest/en/html/runtime-config-load-balancing.html#GUC-WHITE-FUNCTION-LIST